# Finding minimum using lagrange

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry, triangles, volume, lagrange-multiplier

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be the length of a perpendicular drawn to each side from a point inside the equilateral triangle with one side length of $2$.

At this time
$$I = x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2 - xy - yz - zx.$$

Find the minimum of it.

Since I have to find the condition or the constraint. My question is why the constrain have to be *area of the triangle*

Here the constrain is the area of ​​the triangle that is 
$x + y + z = \sqrt{3}$(area)

I dont know how to get it. I know the area of triangle is $\sqrt 3$ but why it is $x+y+z$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z$, which says that $0$ is a minimal value of $I$.

I think using of Lagrange multipliers here is unnecessary, but if you wish...

Since
$$C=\{(x.y,z)|x\geq0,y\geq0,z\geq0\}$$
is a compact and $I$ is a continuous function on $C$,

we see that $I$ gets on $C$ the minimal value.

Let $(x,y,z)$ is a minimum point of $I$.

There are two cases.

1. $xyz=0$.

Let $x=0$.

Hence, $$I=y^2-yz+z^2=\left(y-\frac{z}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3z^2}{4}\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=0$;

2. $xyz\neq0$.

Hence, we need 
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}=2x-y-z=0,$$ 
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial y}=2y-x-z=0$$ and
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial z}=2z-x-y=0,$$
which gives $x=y=z$ and since $I(x,x,x)=0$ again, we got that $0$ is a minimal value.

If you want to get a value of $x+y+z$ then it's just a length of an altitude of the triangle, id est, $\frac{2\sqrt3}{2}=\sqrt3.$

Because you can calculate the area of the triangle twice:
$$\frac{2\cdot x}{2}+\frac{2\cdot y}{2}+\frac{2\cdot z}{2}=\frac{2\cdot \sqrt3}{2}$$

Comment: thankyou! $x + y + z = \sqrt{3}$ i was confuse how to produce this equation? if it is length of an altitute of triangle then it is produced by $\sqrt (4-1)= \sqrt 3$? so $x= \sqrt 3$ ? why $x + y + z = \sqrt{3}$ and not $3 \sqrt 3$ ? and why i have to use this as constraint? is it by guessing?

Comment: @fiksx  I calculated the area of the triangle twice. See please my post.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what do you mean by twice??$\frac{2\cdot x}{2} -> area +\frac{2\cdot y}{2} -> area+\frac{2\cdot z}{2} ->area=\frac{2\cdot \sqrt3}{2} ->area$ 3area=one area(?)

Comment: @fiksx If $M$ is the point inside the triangle $ABC$  then $S_{\Delta ABC}=S_{\Delta MBC}+S_{\Delta AMC}+S_{\Delta ABM}$ or $\frac{2\cdot \sqrt3}{2}=\frac{2\cdot x}{2}+\frac{2\cdot y}{2}+\frac{2\cdot z}{2}$. Draw it!

Comment: suppose P,Q,O is the point in AB,BC,CA,,is the area equal to $\frac {ABxMO}{2}x\frac {BCxMQ}{2}x\frac {CAxMP}{2}$ ?? but x isnt the same as CM, BM, AM right?

Comment: @fiksx $MP=z$, $MQ=x$ and $MO=y$. Right? $AB=BC=AC$. Right?  $S_{\Delta ABM}=\frac{AB\cdot PM}{2}=\frac{2z}{2}=z$. Right? Now, end it!

Comment: OH I got it... it was the point inside,,i misinterpreted the question...  and also if i use lagrange multiplier i need the constrain, is it found by guessing?

Comment: @fiksx I added something.

Comment: thankyou!! sorry i ask many questions.the hard part using lagrange is i have to find the constraint which sometimes isnt provided. but i also dont know another way beside use lagrange to solve this question. here how do you know there are two cases?  and also if there is no constraint can i differentiate it directly like you did to find the x,y,z relation?

Comment: @fiksx The minimal value occurs or in the critical point, where all $\frac{\partial I}{\partial}=0$ or in the boundary of the region $C$, which happens for $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$. If you wish a condition then since the inequality $I\geq0$ is homogeneous, we can assume $x+y+z=1$ and our function will be $L(x,y,z,\lambda)=I+\lambda(x+y+z-1)$. The rest is the same.

Comment: $I=12∑cyc(x−y)2≥0.$ can you explain how to get this equation and $I\geq0$ condition? and also for condition, seems like i can assume anything as long as it is constant(?) like area, or homogeneous(?)

Comment: @fiksx I am ready to answer all question, but ask please one question $I\geq0$ because it's a sum of squares. Also, $I=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}(x-y)^2$ it's just $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz=\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)$.

Comment: thankyou so much!! your answer really help me to understand the problem!! and sorry i asked too many questions!!

Comment: @fiksx You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $x+y+z$ is constant and is equal to the height of the triangle $h=\sqrt{2^2-1^2}=\sqrt 3$. Nothing to do with the area. Indeed you can join the internal point with the vertices of the triangle and get $3$ triangles (see the picture below)

The sum of the areas of the three triangles is obviously the area of the equilateral triangle $\dfrac{fm}{2}+\dfrac{gn}{2}+\dfrac{ph}{2}=\dfrac{f\cdot CH}{2}$

as $f=g=h$ we can collect in the LHS

$\dfrac{f}{2}(m+n+p)=\dfrac{f\cdot CH}{2}$

and therefore $m+n+p=CH$ as I stated above.

The minimum is achieved when the point $D$ is the baricenter of the triangle. Setting the gradient to null

$I_x=2 x - y - z=0$

$I_y=-x + 2 y - z=0$

$I_z=-x - y + 2 z=0$

we get $x=y=z$

and as $x+y+z=\sqrt 3$ we have the minimum when

$x=y=z=\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3}$

and $I=0$

[image]

Comment: thankyou so much!!! first is it necessary to use lagrange multiplier? instead of using lagrange should i use $f_{xy}^2 \times f_{xx} \times f_{yy} <0 $ and $f_{xx}<0$ then it is local minimum? in your answer what is the function of this $m+n+p=CH$ when you can find the $x,y,z$ relation by differentiate it?

Comment: $x+y+z=\sqrt 3$ is where I substituted the result of the system $f_x=0;\;f_y=0;\;f_z=0$ which gave me the information $x=y=z$. Substituting in $f(x,y,z)$ I got $0$ and I did not use the Hessian to prove that it was a minimum, but actually I should have done this passage

Comment: okay thankyou!! but here we need to know xyz relation $x+y+z=\sqrt 3$, how do you know that i have to use this equation for this problem since it wasnot stated in the problem? did you guess it? or is it okay to use any constant as equation?